# How can I prove that this set is equidistributed?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

> By definition we say that a sequence $x_n$ in $(0,1)$ is equidistributed if for all $0<a<b<1$ $$\frac{1}{N} |\{n=1,...,N:x_n\in (a,b)\}|\stackrel{N\rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} b-a$$Now assume that for all $g\in C([0,1])$ with $g(0)=g(1)=0$ we have $$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N g(x_n)\stackrel{N\rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} \int_0^1 g(x)dx~~~~(1)$$I need to show that $(x_n)$ is equidistributed.

My problem is that I don't see where to start. I don't see why $(1)$ should be enough to show that the sequence is equidistributed. I neither see it intuitively nor mathematically. Thus I can't give a huge approach because I am still trying to understand what's going on here. Now I wanted to ask if someone could help me nevertheless?

I see that somehow $(1)$ tells me that $g$ is Riemann integrable, so I mean the sum there converges to a Riemann sum if I remember correctly.

Comment: $g$ is continuous by assumption so it is Riemann-integrable. Try proving first that (1) being true for continuous functions implies it is also true for indicator functions. Then conclude.

Comment: Hint, you want to choose $g$ such that when you apply $(1)$ to it you get back the equidistributed definition. The $g$ you choose is pretty clearly $g = 1$ on $(a, b)$ but $0$ everywhere else. Problem of course is that it's not continuous. But you can construct a sequence of continuous functions that strongly converge to this $g$, which should give you the result for this $g$ itself.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch perfect thanks for the hint I will try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g^* = 1_{(a,b)}$. This is not continuous, but we can approximate $g^*$ in the following way:

Pick some $\epsilon>0$ and let $g$ be the function whose graph joins the points $(0,0), (a-\epsilon, 0), (a, 1), (b,1), (b+\epsilon, 0), (1,0)$.

Then $\int |g-g^*| \le \epsilon$ and $\int g^* = b-a$.

Note that $\sum_{n=1}^N g(x_n) \ge | \{ n | x_n \in (a,b) \}|$.

A similar analysis provides a lower bound and taking limits yields the desired conclusion.

Comment: Is it possible that your last point is wrong there? I think it should be $(0,1)$ shouldn't it?

Comment: No, that is the whole point of the construction.

Comment: But I mean you go from $(b+\epsilon, 0)$ to $(b,0)$. But then on the interval $[b,b+\epsilon]$ you assign one $x$ value multiply $y$ values?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. The idea is to approximate $g^*$ in a continuous way.

Comment: Right I thought this was a typo, but then everything worked for me thanks a lot!

Comment: Why the downvote?